# what does the TSTP stand for in killing signals?

Tags: linux, process, kill

I know that the TSTP will stop the process that were executing, and the signal id is 20, and it's equal to ctrl+z.

I searched for the abbreviation, but i didn't find anything!
anybody know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Literally "**t**emporary **st**o**p**".

You can find it mentioned in old(er) papers such as [*Evolving the UNIX System Interface to Support Multithreading Programs*](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-RR-21.pdf) (Paul R. McJones and Garret F. Swart, September 28, 1987):

> If a signal is received
>   for  which  no  handler procedure was  registered,  a default action  takes place.   Depending  on  the signal,
>   the default action is either to do nothing, to terminate the process, to stop the process temporarily, or to
>   continue the stopped process.
>
> ...
>
> To stop a process,  send it a stop signal (e.g.,  SigTStp;  see page 44).   To restart a stopped process,
>   send it a continue signal (SigCont).

By the way, 4.3BSD's `<signal.h>` has a different slant:

```
#define SIGTSTP 18      /* stop signal from tty */
```

Answer (score 5):

Terminal SToP. It's a catchable signal, usually generated from the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl Z</kbd>.

Contrast with STOP, which has the same effect but cannot be caught.

See POSIX [signal.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html)